# show viewpager tabs without loading/progressbar while loading data

Tags: android, android-viewpager, broadcastreceiver, android-progressbar, viewpagerindicator

I am implementing to show data in **`View Pager`** which is received through **`Broad Cast Receiver`** in *`onReceive()`*.

But my exact requirement is, For first time I need to read whole data and after classification of data depending on size of those ArrayList `size()` I need to check whether that tab have any  data or not after that i need to display *`NODATA`* in **`ViewPager`**.

I have achieved this by using *`Async`*.But my problem after launching first time till reading the data it is showing message as **`NODATA`**.

How to avoid this?

***Note: My requirement is don't show any loading bar or progress bar while loading data***

`code sample`

```
public class InformationTabsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        -
        -
        -
    mAsync = new LoadNotificationsASYNC(this);
        mAsync.execute();
        -
        -
        -

    }
    public void getNotificationsList()
    {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICEE");
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("command", "list");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

        -
        -
        -
    private class LoadNotificationsASYNC extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        Context context;

        public LoadNotificationsASYNC(Context mContext)
        {
            context = mContext;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {

            getNotificationsList();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
        }
            -
            -
            -

        lass NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public NotificationReceiver()
        {
        }

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            //Read broadcastIntent and clacify by properties

            if(some cond..)
            {
                mInformationFragment.updateInformationsList();
            }
            else
            {
                mExecutionFragment.updateExecutionsList();
            }


        }

    }
```

`InformationFragment.java`

```
public class InformationFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener
{
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if (mInformationsList.size() == 0)
        {
            tv_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_info.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_infomation_message));
        }
        else
        {
            tv_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

        -
        -
        -
    public void updateInformationsList()
    {
        if (mInformationsList.size() == 0 && infoTab.firstOnreceiveDone)
        {
            tv_info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_info.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_infomation_message));
            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use `AsyncTask`. Just implement it `onPreExecute()`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //set your message to show nothing til the result come in onPostExecute()
    }
```

Comment: I tried this. But that notification is showing every time for sometime before getting the data using **onReceive()**.

Comment: You need to add some code to understand what you done and what you try to acheive